# Django view returns Httpresponse that blocks on multiprocess

Tags: python, django, multiprocessing

I am making a simple Django JSON REST API:

```
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
@csrf_exempt
def upload_tariff(request, tariff_name, year, month, day, traffic_type):
    new_tariff = Tariff(
        name=tariff_name,
        date=datetime_dt,
        tariff_type=default_tariff_type,
        traffic_type=traffic_type,
        tariff_file=uploaded_file,
        max_loss=None
    )

    logging.info('------------------Before saving---------------------')
    new_tariff.save()
    logging.info('******************After saving***********************')

    updateobject_id = new_tariff.updateobject_set.all()[0].pk
    logging.info('-----------------updateobject id %s--------------' % updateobject_id)
    mapping_json = {
        'mapping': {
            mapping_obj.switch.node: mapping_obj.i_tariff
            for mapping_obj in new_tariff.tariffmapping_set.all()
            }
    }
    logging.info('----------------mapping %s----------' % mapping_json)
    mapping_json.update({'updateobject_id': updateobject_id})
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(mapping_json), content_type='application/json', status=200)
```

Behind new_tariff.save() are 5 sub-processes using multiprocess that run for a while. Therefore, I made the subprocess non-blocking, i.e. I didn't join them. However, when I fire off the post request, it still takes awhile to get a response back which means the response is blocking on the subprocess to finish. Now look at the log:

```
Jul  4 21:30:27 ip-xx-x-x-xx ------------------Before saving---------------------
Jul  4 21:30:29 ip-xx-x-x-xx ******************After saving***********************
Jul  4 21:30:29 ip-xx-x-x-xx -----------------updateobject id 264--------------
Jul  4 21:30:29 ip-xx-x-x-xx ----------------mapping {'mapping': {1: 964, 2: 700, 3: 696, 4: 771, 5: 693}}----------
Jul  4 21:30:41 ip-xx-x-x-xx subprocess 2 started
Jul  4 21:30:42 ip-xx-x-x-xx subprocess 4 started
Jul  4 21:30:51 ip-xx-x-x-xx subprocess 1 started
Jul  4 21:30:52 ip-xx-x-x-xx subprocess 5 started
Jul  4 21:30:55 ip-xx-x-x-xx subprocess 3 started
```

Clearly, an HttpResponse should have been returned but that is not what I am seeing.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: why are you calling .all() and querying every item in the db? why not .filter() and get the specific object? this query updateobject_id = new_tariff.updateobject_set.all()[0].pk is running after you are logging logging.info('----------------mapping %s----------' % mapping_json) - very expensive call to get 1 record

Comment: @Incognos not at all true. The query is a) scoped to objects that relate to `new_tariff` and b) sliced to a single item anyway, so it's only querying one single object.

Comment: d'oh missed the next line where he prints it out.... and just looked up docs to match your statement to first() https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#first - learn something new everyday :-)